# Modifing Pagination-Sorting Method to Change Rows Per Page

Tags: php, mysql, html, pagination

Hi i have a **PHP based** Pagination and Sorting Method which works fine.

I am able to sort and paginate according to any categories, but having problems when it comes to rows per page.

**i have used GET Method to fetch information for pagination and sorting as**

```
    if (isset($_GET['rpp'])&& is_numeric($_GET['rpp'])) {
    $rowsperpage = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['rpp']);
}else{
    $rowsperpage='5';
}
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
   $currentpage = (int) mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
} else {
   $currentpage = 1;
}
if (isset($_GET['order']) && in_array($_GET['order'], $order)) {
    $orderby = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['order']);
}else{
    $orderby='id';
}
$sortby = '';
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sortby = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sort']);
}else{
    $sortby='desc';
}
```

**for pagination i have used following type of url string**

```
echo " <li><a href='$pagename?order=$orderby&sort=$sortby&rpp=$rowsperpage&page=$nextpage'>Next&raquo;&raquo;</a>
```

**and my mysql query is**

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM internet_security ORDER BY $orderby $sortby LIMIT $rowsperpage OFFSET $offset";
```

**and in html i have used links to sort categories like**

```
        <a href="?order=id&sort=desc">id-desc:</a>
        <a href="?order=id&sort=asc">id-asc:</a>

        <a href="?order=title&sort=desc">title-desc:</a>
        <a href="?order=title&sort=asc">title-asc:</a>

        **limit rows by**
        <a href="?&rpp=5">5</a>
        <a href="?&rpp=10">10</a>
        <a href="?&rpp=20">20</a>
```

**My question is** 
every thing is working fine except when i limit row per page via limit rows by - rows get limited to whatever **limit**(5,10,20) is **selected** but then if i click pagination **every thing goes to its default set value** i.e by id and in DESC order with LIMIT of 5.

**and if i do it like**

```
            <a href="?order=id&sort=desc&rpp=5">id-desc:</a>
            <a href="?order=id&sort=desc&rpp=10">id-desc:</a>            
            <a href="?order=id&sort=desc&rpp=20">id-desc:</a>
```

then it works but then i must have at least 12 links for full functionality.which is not a standard approach.

what i want is once a limit is set either by default or by sorting options, i shall be able to sort by id title etc.. and paginatin should works along with it.

i hope i made it clear. 
please see what i am doing wrong and suggest any possible solution to my approach.

Comment: you need to build your URL by java-script function do it dynamically according to the dom elements in your page

Comment: Sidenote: mysql_reaL_escape_string (as its name suggests) is useless for ints, your check for it being a number is already enough (you could also cast to int)

Comment: Store `$rpp` in a `$_SESSION` variable, updating only if it's present in `$_GET`.

Comment: @HAIM EVGI i am avoiding using javascript as i will be using AJAX after php functionallity get to work. so than even if javascript is turned off php can take over

Comment: @ Damien Pirsy got it Note taken down thank.

Comment: @eggyal can you post an example how exactly to do it, it will be a great help as i have not worked with $_SESSION variable till yet.

Answer (score 0):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

Store `$rpp` in a `$_SESSION` variable, updating only if it's present in `$_GET`:

```php
    if ( isset($_GET[    'rpp'])) $_SESSION['rpp'] = intval($_GET['rpp']);
elseif (!isset($_SESSION['rpp'])) $_SESSION['rpp'] = 5;
```

Then use `$_SESSION['rpp']` in your query:

```
$sql2 = "
  SELECT   *
  FROM     internet_security
  ORDER BY $orderby $sortby
  LIMIT    $_SESSION[rpp] OFFSET $offset
";
```

Comment: what about the html link formats, shall it be like <a href="?order=title&sort=asc">title-asc:</a>

Comment: @TallboY: Links of that form will continue with the existing number of rows per page; the user will, at some point, need to use a different link (that includes the `&rpp=` part) to select the number of rows they wish to see.

Comment: ya thats what i am asking, what i shall do about it, i can not do it like <a href="?order=id&sort=desc&rpp=5">id-desc:</a> it will then again be problem of lot of links

Comment: @TallboY: This is really a user interface issue, regarding how you wish to present the user with the choice of the number of items to show per page.  I have often seen a `<select>` dropdown box on a `<form>` that is either submitted manually or by handling the `onchange` event...

Comment: if i use <select> dropdown box and POST  method the logic is almost same and i have to make lots of option in that too

Comment: @Tallboy: No - the only options within the `<select>` would be the permissible number of results per page... to set the column on which to order results (and the sort direction), it's more usual to have little triangles at the top of each column that link to e.g. `?order=id&sort=desc` - you could then do something similar to the above to set (and remember) those settings in `$_SESSION` too.  Then the previous/next buttons would only concern themselves with `$offset`.

Comment: hey i got it to work thanks anyways for your time appreciate  it i made some few changes like displaying links via php not html and passing variables not values.and it's working